# How to call or send sms to a three digit number with sim800l?

Tags: arduino, sim800

Trying to call or send sms to a number that's not a phone number with sim800l via arduino results to an error. Does anyone knows how i can send an sms to a three digit number(for example, a network provider's number.). I need it for a project.

Comment: I'd recommend also posting on this site: https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the exact error code you are getting? (Remember that you still to need add full country postal code to your number)